# Why RXJS angular behaviorSubject emit mutiple values

Tags: angular, rxjs, behaviorsubject

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYqBH.png)I use `BehaviorSubject` to share data between my app components, I have a performance issue due to mutiple emission of same value from `BehaviorSubject`. For instance,  I call http to get team Object from backend and store it in a behaviorSubject, many components subscribe to this `BehaviorSubject`. Each component gets the value from  subscription and does a sequence of manipulations on the value. The essence of the problem is that the value is emitted many times and each component does all sequence a few times. My guess is the the `BehaviorSubject` emits the value as number of subscribers. I couldn't find anything in Google which is very strange to me, what am I missing ?

The number of times the team emit value is different in local compared to deployment. You can see the the printing of "refetch returned value" it is the actual response from http.

Comment: provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: what's the purpose of your `BehaviorSubject` ? If your goal is to share data, why don't you simply store the result of the request in a variable ?

Comment: Actually I think it's relate to the http delay time. So how can I filter those fake emission without any value.

Comment: hi  Youkoulele, the purpose is to be able to subscribe to this value and update each component according to the last value stored

Comment: You should provide at least the relevant parts of your code, or even better a stackblitz so we can find what's wrong in your implementation

Comment: my guess is that you are somehow converting the `Observable` from `HttpClient` into a `BehaviorSubject` when you should have a separate `BehaviorSubject` that you `.next()` when your http request succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

You can partially fix it by only accepting values different than the last one, thus skipping evaluating the same value a few times in a row.

Also, if the data you query can be the same as the previous query, it may be a good idea to add this anyway:

```
import { distinctUntilChanged } from 'rxjs/operators';

this.myService.myObservable
    .pipe(distinctUntilChanged())
    .subscribe(value => {
        console.log(value);
    })
```

Comment: we don't even know what OP tried. I think this is a dirty workaround, there must be a much cleaner solution

Comment: Agreed. It may not be the solution (accepted answer), but it can at least help someone who's struggling with performance issues when multiple identical values are emitted. Also, it may not be a bad idea for OP to add this anyway.

Comment: thanks for the feedback but I still struggle with it.

Comment: @Adam007 It’s very hard to help you when you don’t show us your code. Please do so.

Comment: this.tsub = this.dyn.team$.subscribe(team => { if (team) {
          console.log('team emit value');
}});

Comment: it is in the component and printing multiple times after team$  value updated

Comment: this is how you consume your `BehaviorSubject`. Please update your question and post how you create the  `BehaviorSubject`

Comment: @Adam007 But it’s caused by *something*, and we can only guess now.

Comment: I editied the question, please review. Appreciate your response

Comment: What's the point of an answer that offers a (horrible) "solution" to a question that hasn't been asked here?

Comment: Can it be baecause the object I subscibed to is pretty big and as long as the value loaded to subscriber the subscriber is triggered again and again ?

Comment: I've never heard of that. The whole point of Promises and Observables is that they *wait* for stuff to complete. Also, you still haven't posted any of your code.