# BehaviorSubject emits the same value for every subscription

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have an issue with `BehaviorSubject` emits value for every subscription. So if I have, for example, 2 `this.projectService.projectState$` streams subscribed via, for example, `async` , `tap` on `projectState$` emits twice. Respectively If I have 3 streams, `tap` emits 3 times and so on.  I guess it is similar to this issue [Why RXJS angular behaviorSubject emit mutiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51137505/why-rxjs-angular-behaviorsubject-emit-mutiple-values) but suggested answers non-suitable for me. Besides `distinctUntilChanged()` I have used `shareReplay(1)` but as far as understand it is more for `Observable` to makes it hot but `BehaviorSubject` is already hot and no need of `shareReplay(1)` and it obviously does not work.

`project.service.ts:`

```
projectState: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject(null);
projectState$: Observable<any> = this.projectState.asObservable().pipe(
  distinctUntilChanged(),
  shareReplay(1),
  tap(s => console.log("state", s)) // logged twice the same state
);

projectId$: Observable<string> = this.router.events.pipe(
  startWith(new NavigationEnd(0, "", "")),
  filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
  map(_ => {
    const { primary } = this.router.parseUrl(this.router.url).root.children;
    const segments = primary && primary.segments;

    return segments && segments[4] && segments[4].toString()
  }),
  filter(id => id && !["admin-areas", "profiles"].includes(id)),
  distinctUntilChanged(),
  shareReplay(1)
);


projectInfo$: Observable<any> = this.projectId$.pipe(
  switchMap(id => this.getProjectInfo(id)),
  shareReplay(1)
)

constructor(private http: HttpClient,
            private appService: AppService,
            private router: Router) {
  this.projectInfo$.subscribe(
    info => this.projectState.next(info)
  )
}
```

`header.component.ts` here 2 `this.projectService.projectState$` streams subscribed via `async`

```
projectName$: Observable<string> = this.projectService.projectState$.pipe(
  filter(info => info),
  map(info => info.name)
);

versionName$: Observable<string> = this.projectService.projectState$.pipe(
  filter(info => info),
  map(info => info.modelVersionsList),
  map(versions => versions.find(v => v.id === this.projectService.getCurrentVersionId())),
  filter(v => v),
  map(v => v.title)
);
```

`header.component.html`

```
<div>{{projectName$ | async}} - {{versionName$ | async} </div>
```

Comment: For me it's a bit difficult to find the problem because of the complexity of this code.I think your code could be simpler without using the BehaviourSubject, just derrive projectState$ from mapping projectInfo$ would make it easier to understand.

Comment: `BehaviorSubject` emits its default value on every subscription so what you're describing seems to be the correct behavior.

Comment: @MarcelHoekstra, I need a `BehaviourSubject` to change `projectState$` via `next`

Comment: I think this will do the same: projectState$ = this.projectInfo$.pipe(map(info=>
  this.projectState.next(info)
))

Answer (score 0):

Try using rxjs's built in operator called **takeLast()**,

More info [here](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/takeLast).